# Unhiding apps resets the app layout in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm

I want to hide the apps by MDM server. I can able to hide and unhide the apps but in unhiding the app layout resets and all the folder structure gone as well. I need to develop an app such that which will keep the layout fixed. I have read all the documentation but could not figure out how to develop such app?
I want to develop app similar to https://screentimelabs.com/layoutfixer/

Please let me know if any one has any idea how to achieve the same.